# Multilevel/Nested expand collapse for dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of years containing months and I am trying to display the years as the top level and the months as a nested level where each month contains number of records.The id generated would be dynamic. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[id^="button"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="+" ? $(this).val("-"):$(this).val("+"));
  $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
         $('input[id^="but"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="+" ? $(this).val("-"):$(this).val("+"));
            $('div[id^="level"]').slideToggle();
  
 });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button0" type="button" value="+">year
<div id="expanderContent" style="display:none">
    <input id="but1" type="button" value="+">content1<br />
        <div id="level1">l1<br/>
            l1<br/>
            l1<br/>
         </div>
 <input id="but2" type="button" value="+">content2<br />
        <div id="level2">l1<br/>
            l1<br/>
            l1<br/>
        </div>   
 content3<br />
 content4<br />
 content5<br />
</div>
```

```
    content3<br />
    content4<br />
    content5<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
 $('input[id^="but"]').click(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == "+" ? $(this).val("-") : $(this).val("+"));
     $(this).nextAll("div:first").slideToggle();
 });
```

Toggle the div element which is coming next after the clicked button element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdLwvmxp/75/)